# Issues with animating view with bottom constraint

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout

I have been trying to animate the bottom constraint of a view within its parent view without any success. The event that triggers the view animation is a keyboardWillShow event and I want my view to lay on top of the keyboard. Here is my code within the keyboard observer.

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.view.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

        if((constraint.secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeBottom) && (constraint.secondItem == self.messageContainerView))
        {

            NSLog(@"will change value");
            constraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height;

        }


    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{


        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    }];
```

within the storyboard file these are the properties of the vertical space -bottom constraint

- firstItem : Bottom Layout Guide.Top
- relation : equal
- secondItem : viewthatwillanimate.Bottom

I am successfully satisfying the condition but I do not see my view animate or move.

Comment: You don't have any animation in the block. Also, if you create an IBoutlet for your constraint you can avoid the search.

Comment: I have tried to create an outlet but that did not work. What do you mean by animation block? I call the [UIView animateWithDuration:] and pass in a block that call the parent view's layoutifNeeded

Comment: You should actually change some property, in this case `constraint.constant`, inside the block

Comment: Just tried to create the outlet again and set the constraint within the animation block. Then I called the parent views layoutifneeded but no luck..

Comment: Ok.  I just looked up some of my code - this is what I have - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/2e62d4314d45e5270e1f self.keyboardHeight is the constraint that sets the Y position of the bottom most element

Comment: I really appreciate you tagging along here, I tried the exact same solution and nothing works, I even created a new project and tested it out and it works on the other project, so It must be something with my specific view.

Comment: Good news, it works now. The flaw laid on my part, I had accidentally left some old code the set the frame of the view I was trying to animate. I commented that out and it works, thanks for the help mate.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted